# querying dates in mysql returning nothing?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am trying to query a database table that has values like so

```
id = 1
tablename = 1 (bigint)
timestampstart = 2011-08-06 13:54:17 (timestamp)
timestampend = 2011-08-06 14:54:17 (timestamp)
```

so I'm using this function to try to return the database name that the timestamp I provide is inbetween start and end timestamps

```
function getDatabase($timestamp){
    $link = new MySQLi($host, $root, $password, $database);
    $name = '';

$result = $link->query("SELECT `tablename` FROM `datas` WHERE `timestampstart` =< '$timestamp' AND `timestampend` >= '$timestamp'");
if($link->error){
    return $link->error;
}
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $name .= $row['tablename'];
    }

    return $name;
}else{
    return 'no table';
}
}
```

so I call it like this

```
echo getDatabase('2011-08-06 13:54:50');
```

and all I get is 'no table' back 
there is only that one row at the top where I defined the structure of my table, any help will be greatly appreciated thank you for your time.

Comment: See your `SELECT` query, `=<` should be `<=`

Comment: I'm still getting 'no table'

Comment: is there datas table in your db?

Comment: yes the data is in the table how I showed it above

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: no errors I'm trying to figure out how to see if there are errors

Comment: do you get it? 'no table'

Comment: yes I get 'no table'

Comment: Did you check datatype of timestampstart and timestampend column?

Comment: it is timestamp

Comment: really ,is there a table with name 'datas' ??

Comment: yes there is a table named 'datas'

Comment: `$timestamp` you are feeding same variable in start and end timestamp.

Comment: no I just pasted them in myself how they are up there

Comment: then you are giving two different value for start and end timestamp?

Comment: yes they are listed above

Comment: And the difference is one hours. so check manually how many rows are in that one hours.

Comment: theres only one row, the one listed above

Comment: your query can work without conditions?

Comment: I'm still getting 'no table' without conditions

Comment: Is that php code is same the one you are executing or you have edited to paste it in stackoverflow.

Comment: var_export($result);  before if($link->error)...tell what's that?

Comment: @JRowan I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function in your `SELECT` query to compare the timestamps. Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT `tablename` 
FROM `datas` 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestampstart) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$timestamp') 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestampend) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$timestamp')
```

Or, (a shorter query)

```
SELECT `tablename` 
FROM `datas` 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$timestamp') BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestampstart) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestampend)
```

Apart from that, I can also see scope issue because `$host`, `$root`, `$password` and `$database` are not available in the scope of your function. Either use `global` or pass the database credentials to your `getDatabase()` function as function parameters.

Comment: I used the global keyword for the variables and it worked, thank you I never heard of that before I'm still new to php

Comment: @JRowan Glad I could help. *Happy coding! :-)*